# htaccess redirect based on a user that not logged in to log in

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page that a user has to sign in and log out off it. I have created a session that will break a session. A user can still access the page directly without logging in. I heard about htaccess. How do I go around creating that page and making sure no one can access the page without logging into the page?

Comment: Why not just check in your code if session is properly set and if not - redirect? I don't think htaccess has anything to do with sessions, cookies and so on

Comment: What is it actually that you refer to when you write of a "session"?

Comment: Sorry for not exampling well. What I am mean about creating a session Is a session is started when a user logs in and gets destroyed when they log out. What I need the htaccess page for is to make sure that the page they logging into can't be accessed unless a user can log in for the log in page.